# Java DirContext sreach only few records

Tags: java, ldap

When I try to search records by using query `(testAtt=1)` in Apache Directory Studio they showing me `17062` records and when I run the same query on my Java code they get only `8531` records. My Java Code is given below

```
String searchFilter = propFile.getProperty(Constants.GetAllUsersQuery);
String ldapSearchBase = propFile.getProperty(Constants.eDir_SearchBase);
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> resultsApp = ctx.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);
int i = 0;
while (resultsApp.hasMoreElements()) {
    SearchResult result = (SearchResult) resultsApp.next();
    String DN = "";
    DN = result.getNameInNamespace();
    if (!DN.isEmpty()) {
        eDir_AllUsersDNList.add(i, DN);
        i++;
    }
    resultsApp.nextElement();
}

System.out.println("eDir_AllUsersDNList : "+eDir_AllUsersDNList.size());
```

Please help me to find out the issue.
I am using Java 8.

Comment: What LDAP Server?

Comment: @jwilleke The problem is in the code, and what the LDAP server is is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (resultsApp.hasMoreElements()) {
    SearchResult result = (SearchResult) resultsApp.next();
    String DN = "";
    DN = result.getNameInNamespace();
    if (!DN.isEmpty()) {
        eDir_AllUsersDNList.add(i, DN);
        i++;
    }
    resultsApp.nextElement();
}
```

Remove the final `nextElement()` call. It is doing nothing useful, and it is skipping all the even-numbered elements. Note that 8531 is half of 17062.

NB the cast is redundant, and the DN can't be empty, and providing an initializer for it when you assign it on the very next line is pointless.